# Selecting emails from database to send form info to

Tags: php, mysql, database, email

I am currently trying to send information gathered from user inputted data through a form to email addresses which are stored in the database, i dont know if this is possible. At the minute i have them being sent to my own email, as a test, is there any way of selecting and sending the info to the emails within the columns in my table in the database. Heres the code i have

```
require 'mail/class.simple_mail.php';
$mailer = new SimpleMail();

$comments = $_REQUEST['comments'];
$time = $_REQUEST['time'];
$date = $_REQUEST['date'];
$place = $_REQUEST['place'];


$message = "<strong>This is an email from the bride to you the bridesmaids, here is the information on the next dress fitting<br />".$date." ".$time." ".$place." ".$comments." </strong>";



$send   = $mailer->setTo('targetemail@example.com', 'Your Email')
                 ->setSubject('Dress Fitting')
                 ->setFrom('myemail@myemail.com', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Reply-To', 'myemail@myemail.com', 'Domain.com')
                 ->addMailHeader('Cc', 'myemail@myemail.com', 'Bill Gates')
                 ->addGenericHeader('Content-Type', 'text/html; charset="utf-8"')
                 ->setMessage($message)
                 ->setWrap(100)
                 ->send();
echo ($send) ? 'Your Email has been sent to your bridesmaids' : 'Could not send email';
```

Comment: Yes it is possible.  Reading from a MySQL database with PHP is PHP 101.  There are 1000 tutorials on the 'net to show you how to do so.

Comment: ok @Madbreaks but will i be editing that code or will it be code from scratch?